# Will my traffic come back after my site redesign?

Tags: seo, google, 301-redirect, traffic

I screwed up. I launched my site after rebuilding it without setting up the proper 301's and traffic immediately dropped about 60%(it's not really something I thought about). After about a week and a half, I set the 301's back up yesterday and resubmitted my sitemap to google. Google has yet to index the whole thing, but traffic isn't getting any better. Is it likely to come back?

If so, I. How long? Has this happened to you?

Answer (score 2):

It's happened to people I know and they lost tens of thousands. From ranking on the first page for dozens of keywords to none can kill a business. If you've setup 301's and you resubmitted a sitemap that's all you can do as far as letting Google know you're still up and running.

No one can say how long. It's something you'll have to be patient for.

Answer (score 1):

It should come back, but it depends on a lot of factors how long does it take. The most important factor is, how big your site is. I suggest you to second check that all the redirects are in place:

- menu entries
- submenu entries
- tags
- articles, blog posts
- static pages, like contact page, privacy policy, etc...
- static images and downloadable media like pdf-s, videos, etc ...

The new sitemap have to contain only the new pages.

You should wait for at least 3 months for your traffic to come back. If it's not happening, you can try to move the whole site to a brand new domain with proper redirections.

Answer (score 0):

In WMT you can add to index URL's manually and in my experience Google will crawl them within a week( 1-2 days usually).

It is difficult to say if you'll get back rankings due to regular updates being released by Google causing algorithmic changes. For a young site yes it will be difficult to get back rankings in case some competition is there.